# Maintain ID attr changes with CSS

Tags: html, css

Let's say I have an ID attribute, so targeting ID with CSS is very simple:

```
<style>
#idAttr { color: #a2a2a2 }
</style>
```

How to maintain my CSS so it could be future-proof ? If in future the ID attribute would change, to let's say #idAttr2. How this can be done with no writing code for this attribute?

Comment: Don't bind styles to id, if you expect it to change. You can use many other CSS selectors.

Comment: use Class styles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This is a case where using an ID selector probably isn't appropriate**. The problem is that you're binding something that you believe shouldn't change (the style of the element) to something that you believe might change (the ID of the element).

**Since the style shouldn't change, you should bind it to something that shouldn't change**. If you need the ID to be able to change, then you should also give the element a class that shouldn't change, and put the styles on that.

Answer (score 1):

In css you have a selector which may help with that.

```
div[id^="t-"] {
    background: #ffff00;
}
```

This will select all id's that begin with `t-`, like `t-5555-5505-5555`

The best practice in many cases would be to style the elements using classes but I don't know what you are using it for.

Answer (score 1):

Use [CSS Class Selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_class.asp)

```css
#id1
{
 color: red;
}

#id2
{
 color: green;
}

.span-style
{
 border: solid 1px gray;
}
```

```html
<span id="id1" class="span-style">My id is id1 and have a common span-style</span>
<br />
<br />
<span id="id2" class="span-style">My id is id2 and have a common span-style</span>
```